# Why was there a 'J' letter on the trap?

Tags: indiana-jones

In the movie *Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade (1989)*  there is a scene with a dreathtrap:

The joke is, naturally, that in the classical latin alphabet there was no 'j' letter.
Which brings the question why was there a 'j' letter on the plate at all? Or perhaps it was a different one distorted by time, or a cracked plate?

Comment: Been a while but the trap could have been created when Latin was no longer prevalent. They then choose a Latin word knowing that the J is likely to throw some people off. Alternatively, the traps could have been updated over time.

Comment: While technically the people who built this trap should not be native speakers of modern English, I would also assume that the letter was added as part of that trap by people (the knight?) who spoke a language that had a "J". Wikipedia says that "Jehova" first appeared around the 16th century, while in the 12th, it would have been more likely "Yehowa".

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot missed that one. Yep, clear dupe, VTC'd.

Comment: @Morrigan I only saw it when I did some googling for an answer myself so don't worry about it. You should be able to VTC it yourself though :)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot just did, thanks.

Comment: I am just getting acclimated to Stack Exchange, so I am curious why this was marked as a duplicate. Just because the answer and/or comments to a previous question includes the answer to a new question doesn't make the new one "an exact duplicate" of the old question. What am I missing? (Please note I'm not arguing, just wondering.)